# If Else not working?

Tags: java, regex, if-statement, jbutton, actionlistener

My `If Else` statement in my Action Listener is not working properly.

When Jbutton is pressed, if user has entered a String with digit `0-9` and `+-*/`, then program is executed properly.

Else, JOptionPane shows an error message.

In the code below, it seems to skip the `If` condition and go directly to `Else` no matter what???

*If you decide to compile this code..

Example Postfix: 11+ would equal (1+1) when converted to Infix*

**Main**

```
    package p2gui;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Mike
 */
public class P2GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Three Address Generator");// Title

    private final JButton evaluate;
    private final JLabel textfieldLabel;
    private final JTextField entryField;
    private final JLabel resutfieldlabel;
    private final JTextField resultField;
    private final JOptionPane popup = new JOptionPane();

    P2GUI() {

        f.setSize(425, 180);
        f.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers  
        f.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible  //window size
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textfieldLabel = new JLabel("Enter Postfix Expression");
        f.add(textfieldLabel);
        textfieldLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 160, 25);

        entryField = new JTextField("");
        //entryField.addActionListener(this);//ActionListener
        f.add(entryField);
        entryField.setBounds(160, 10, 220, 25);

        evaluate = new JButton("Construct Tree");

        evaluate.addActionListener(this);//ActionListener
        f.add(evaluate);
        evaluate.setBounds(137, 55, 130, 30);

        resutfieldlabel = new JLabel(" Infix Expression ");
        f.add(resutfieldlabel);
        resutfieldlabel.setBounds(20, 100, 100, 25);

        resultField = new JTextField("");
        //resultField.addActionListener(this);//ActionListener
        resultField.setEditable(false);
        f.add(resultField);

        resultField.setBounds(125, 100, 220, 25);
    }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String fullString;
                fullString = entryField.getText().trim();
        if(fullString.matches("\\d+") && fullString.matches("[-+*/]")){

            Convert conversion = new Convert();
                    resultField.setText(conversion.convert(fullString));

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Digit and 
  Arithmetic operator");        
            //eraseTextField();

                }

            }

    public void eraseTextField() {
        entryField.setText("");
        entryField.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P2GUI p1GUI;
        p1GUI = new P2GUI();

    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////END///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

**Covert Class**

```
package p2gui;

import java.util.Stack;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Mike
 */

public class Convert {

    /**
     * Checks if the input is operator or not
     * @param c input to be checked
     * @return true if operator
     */
 private boolean operator(char c){
  return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c =='/' || c == '^';
    }

    /**
     * Converts any postfix to infix
     * @param postfix String expression to be converted
     * @return String infix expression produced
     */
 public String convert(String postfix){
  Stack<String> stackIt = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {
            char c = postfix.charAt(i);
            if (operator(c)) {
                String b = stackIt.pop();
                String a = stackIt.pop();
                stackIt.push("(" + a + c + b + ")");
            } else {
                stackIt.push("" + c);
            }
        }
        return stackIt.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: note that one variable can only contain one values this is the pitfall in the OR and AND operator

Comment: @abcOfJava: No, the OP is trying to find out if the string contains a digit *and* contains an operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matches` checks if the string **as a whole** matches the regular expression. If you want to check for matches *within* the string, you need `.*` at both ends of the expression:

```
if (fullString.matches(".*\\d+.*") && fullString.matches(".*[-+*/].*")){
```

**But**, that allows the user to enter anything, so long as it has at least one digit somewhere, and at least one of the operators somewhere. They can enter anything they like as long as it includes those two pieces.

If you want to check that they've *only* entered digits and operators, and have entered at least one of each:

```
if (fullString.matches("[-+*/\\d]+") && fullString.matches(".*\\d.*") && fullString.matches(".*[-+*/].*")){
```

That says "Only digits and operators, and at least one digit and at least one operator, in any order."

I don't know if you want to lock it down more (digits *then* operator, or operator *then* digits; only one operator; don't allow digits, then operator, then more digits; etc.), but the basic problem with the `if` in question is the "whole string" thing.

Comment: Thanks T.J it works now. I figured it was something really small

Answer (score 0):

The regex `String` that you are using, `"\\d+"` checks if the `String` **only** contains digits, but you want to check if it contains operators as well.  The following regex should suffice (one digit and one operator are required):

```
if (fullString.matches(".*\\d+[-+*/]*.*")) {
    // Code here...
}
```

Comment: That requires the string to have digits followed by an operator, but their code in `convert` seems to allow for any order (and indeed, for combinations). (I don't know whether that's an issue in `convert` or intentional, though.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, just edited it.  I need to brush up on my regex!